# Retrieving appdata from facebook application

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

After almost 2 hours of try I'm posting this here,

I'm trying to retrieve list of parameters passed to my facebook application. Here is my application, https://apps.facebook.com/takeflights/index.php

When I'm loading the app with this URL https://apps.facebook.com/takeflights/index.php?id=5, $signed_request['app_data'] is not returning anything,

below is part of my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        ));

        $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
        print_r($signed_request['app_data']);
```

I'm also searching for "allow signed_request" in application setting but not finding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is only printing the `app_data` part of the signed request. This has to be manually populated by your app via a query string.

To do it, your query should look something like this:

https://apps.facebook.com/takeflights/index.php?appdata=id%3D5%26page%3D1

Comment: Yes it should be included in a parameter like mentioned above, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729587/how-do-i-share-content-from-a-facebook-page-tabs-internal-page/10731516#10731516)

Comment: In my app, i placed these lines, $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
print_r(json_decode($signed_request['app_data']));

then, i'm loading the page with this url,https://apps.facebook.com/takeflights/index.php?app_data={"Redirect_Page":"Home.aspx"}

I'm just trying to check if I get the data but still not getting, do you have any idea why??