# How do I share content from a Facebook Page Tab's internal page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm trying to share content that is on a Page Tab's internal page. Each item on this page has a Like button and I'd like to redirect the user to the page and scroll via JS to the item. Preferably, I'd like to not disclose the site's real url. In other words, to share something like this: https://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGENAME/PAGENUMBER?sk=app_PAGETABNUMBER&app_data=5

The problem is when I try to share the url above, Facebook doesn't take into account the OG tags. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit 1: when I put an url like the one above on Debugger, it says "Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger", so I guess it isn't able to find the og tags.

Edit 2: if I put the site's real url in the data-href of the Like button and in the initial Page Tab page I get the app_data to do a redirect to the internal page with the og tags (where og:url points to the url mentioned above), Facebook ignores the og tags. In the Debugger, it says "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Edit 3: could only get it to work by sharing the real site's url. When a user visits the link, I redirect him to the url above. If the user agent has facebook in its name, I neither load the PHP SDK nor do the redirect, in order to let it retrieve the og tags.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right way to pass variable in url, you need to pass Json like object in app_data like this

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGENAME/PAGENUMBER?sk=app_PAGETABNUMBER&app_data={"Redirect_Page":"Home.aspx"}
```

You can then get the app_data in signed request once you parse app_data as Json object you can access app_data["Redirect_Page"].

Comment: That's not really necessary. In order to send two parameters, I used mine in the following format: g_STRING_i_NUMBER and exploded it.

Answer (score 1):

That should work, the value you provide for `app_data` should be in the signed_request which is posted to your app's code