# Link to a certain page inside a Facebook Tab application

Tags: php, facebook

I'm writing a PHP application that will serve as a Facebook Tab inside of a Page. In the application, the user has the option to Share a photo, be it on Facebook or as a link to put on other websites. The part with Facebook is easy, but my question is this.

How can I give someone a link to a page inside of a Facebook Tab?

For example, the direct url from which the tab loads the website is: *http://my-site.com/tab*

Inside of that website I have an url that looks like *http://my-site.com/tab/photo.php?id=3*

The url of the Facebook Tab is something like http://facebook.com/my-page/app_3932734623842

What I want is for the user to be able to paste a link on their twitter which would lead them directly to the page *http://my-site.com/tab/photo.php?id=3* inside of the Facebook app.

Possible? How? :(

Thank you!

Comment: Your URL gives an error -"The page you requested was not found"

Comment: Have look at it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729587/how-do-i-share-content-from-a-facebook-page-tabs-internal-page/10731516#10731516). In this way you can redirect user to your desired page based on the query string.

Comment: Thanks @MSUH, that works! The data is now in the signed_request and I can redirect the user once he reaches the index page. How do I mark this as answered? :)

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved, To mark it as answer go the same link and Upvote the answer.

Comment: As soon as I have 15 reputation, I registered half an hour ago. :)